# Disable enterkey for next button pyqt5 QWizard

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qwizard

I am making a Wizard in `QWizard`

I have  `QLineEdit` and  `QPushButton`

```
# Enter token
self.enter_token_box = QLineEdit()
# Enter token button
self.btn = QPushButton('OK')
# connect button to function, checks the token..
self.btn.clicked.connect(self._EnterToken)
```

I have put in this line which accepts an enter key press and runs the function the same as clicking the "OK" button.

```
# Enter key press connection
self.enter_token_box.returnPressed.connect(self._EnterToken)
```

The problem is that it will trigger BOTH the `OK` button AND the `Next` button of the wizard.

**MVCE:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Wizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.addPage(EnterToken(self)) 
        self.addPage(ProcessData(self))

class EnterToken(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EnterToken, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setTitle("Enter your token here")
        self.setSubTitle(" ")           

        # Enter Token Widgets
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.enter_token_box = QLineEdit()        

        self.btn = QPushButton('OK')

        # layout options
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)        
        self.label.setText("Enter Your 12 Digit Code.")
        layout.addWidget(self.enter_token_box)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        # Enter Key TRigger
        self.enter_token_box.returnPressed.connect(self._EnterToken)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._EnterToken)

        self.setLayout(layout)        


    def _EnterToken(self):
        """ Method for processing user input after the button is pressed"""

        QMessageBox.about(self, "I want only this!!", "I want only you and not the next page!!")


class ProcessData(QWizardPage):
    """ Sensor Code Entry """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProcessData, self).__init__(parent)        

        # num of logs combo box
        self.num_logs_combo = QComboBox(self)

        # ~buttons
        self.btn = QPushButton('OK')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.num_logs_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)  
        self.setLayout(layout)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wizard = Wizard()
    wizard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you run the code above and click `ok`, you will remain on the page.  Same thing happens if you have anything selected other than the `QLineEdit` box.

If you are in the `QLineEdit` box and you press `Enter`, you will be taken to the next page as well as displaying the messagebox.

How can I stop the `Enter Key` from being linked to the `Next` button.

How can I access and override attributes for the `BACK`, `NEXT` and `FINISH` buttons in `QWizard`?

Comment: you could provide a [mcve], I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: fair point!! I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the buttons you must use the `button()` method and pass the `QWizard::WizardButton`, in your case you must disable the `default` of the QPushButton.

```
class Wizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.addPage(EnterToken(self)) 
        self.addPage(ProcessData(self))

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.button(QWizard.NextButton).setDefault(False)
        super(Wizard, self).showEvent(event)
```

Update:

```
class Wizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.addPage(EnterToken(self)) 
        self.addPage(ProcessData(self))

        self.buttons = [self.button(t) for t in (QWizard.NextButton, QWizard.FinishButton)]

        for btn in self.buttons:
            btn.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj in self.buttons and event.type() == QEvent.Show:
            obj.setDefault(False)
        return super(Wizard, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: I had tried both `setAutoDefault` and `setDefault` before but it was  inside the page classes!! `setDefault` works perfectly in the `Wizard` class.!

Comment: @johnashu You are correct, try both and at the time of copying, delete the incorrect one.

Comment: it works great.. how do i override the finish button?

Comment: I mean I added the same function both auto and without and changed NextButton to FinishButton and it still highlights the finish button..

Comment: Very elegant!.. That is perfect and makes a lot more sense with the pythonistic approach! :)